# Print_r  с условием

Tags: массивы, php

Всем, привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли сделать вывод массива с условием. Ситуация такая, я формирую большой массив, потом его сортирую, а потом мне надо получить например первые **n** элементов отсортированного массива.

Формирую массив:

```
foreach ($array_RESPONSEdata as $key => $row) {
 $new_created_time[$key] = $row['DATE_PIC'];
 $new_thumbnail[$key] = $row['LINK_PIC'];
 $new_tags_name [$key] = $row['TAG_PIC'];
}
```

На выходе получаю массив примерно такого вида:

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1376566005 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage3.s3.amazonaws.com/90ebfcc2059d11e381c522000a9e035f_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[1] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1376222415 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage9.s3.amazonaws.com/957a78a4027d11e3a72522000a1fb586_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[2] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1374685904 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage2.s3.amazonaws.com/1dbe356ef48411e2931722000a1fc67c_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[3] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1373909177 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/0fd9b22adce711e2a7ab22000a1f97eb_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[4] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1372089573 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/0fd9b22adce711e2a7ab22000a1f97eb_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
[5] => Array ( [DATE_PIC] => 1371468982 [LINK_PIC] => http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/0fd9b22adce711e2a7ab22000a1f97eb_5.jpg [TAG_PIC] => test )
)
```

Далее сортирую массив по ключу **DATE_PIC**:

```
array_multisort($new_created_time, SORT_DESC, $array_RESPONSEdata);
```

Получу массив с обратной сортировкой.

**Вопрос:** Как теперь после сортировки вывести допустим первые три строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.

```
print_r(array_slice($array, 0, 3));
```